# how to send this data from local storage to php online using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, local-storage

This is my php codes to received and insert the data into the online database. I am very sure i these fabricated codes will not work but with you education and help i will get. thank you. insertdata.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'function.php';
//Create Object for DB_Functions clas
$db = new DB_Functions(); 
//Get JSON posted by Android Application
$json = $_POST["usersJSON"];
//Remove Slashes
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
$json = stripslashes($json);
}
//Decode JSON into an Array
$data = json_decode($json);
//Util arrays to create response JSON
$a=array();
$b=array();
//Loop through an Array and insert data read from JSON into MySQL DB
for($i=0; $i<count($data) ; $i++)
{
//Store User into MySQL DB
$res = $db->storedata($data[$i]->callid,$data[$i]->pid,$data[$i]->pname,$data[$i]->medstay_amt,$data[$i]->med_amt,$data[$i]->imv_amt,$data[$i]->othermc_amt,$data[$i]->emtrans_amt,$data[$i]->outpden_am,$data[$i]->otherps_amt,$data[$i]->herb_amt,$data[$i]->medban_amt,$data[$i]->othermp_amt,$data[$i]->assist_amt,$data[$i]->code,$data[$i]->date);
    //Based on inserttion, create JSON response
    if($res){
        $b["id"] = $data[$i]->pid;
        $b["status"] = 'yes';
        array_push($a,$b);
    }else{
        $b["id"] = $data[$i]->pid;
        $b["status"] = 'no';
        array_push($a,$b);
    }
}
//Post JSON response back to Android Application
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

Comment: I see you are using jQuery, take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for the correction and quick response.  I will look at it and get back.

Comment: Sorry i am still a newbie. Unfortunately I couldn't create my own codes from that the page content.  Please is it possible to use my codes to help me with if not all but skeleton that I can follow n finish it.

Comment: Do you want to send a request after a click on `.BTN_Submit_Task` or `.BTN_Sub`? and what data do you want to pass? `AllTasks` object?

Comment: Yes sir. Please help me . After a button click the records should be send to my php Web application page . The database table name is question.  Thank you

Comment: Which button? `.BTN_Submit_Task` or `.BTN_Sub`?

Comment: BTN_Submit_Task

Comment: Please any help i have deleted the wrong post and added addition information. Thank you. Some please help me

Comment: Please have uploaded my two files here for your assistants. Thank you. https://github.com/logonia/ihope.git

Comment: Did you take a look at my updated answer?

Comment: @HtmHell please is it from the gethub or the codes on stack overflow sir ?

Comment: You have received a syntax error, I updated the code. Try it again

Comment: @HtmHell. Thank you very much for the response. I have now two different files for my dream project. The jquery file to send the data from local storage and php file to receive and insert the data online. Please which of them have you update for me sir. Can I kindly send the two files for your assistance please please? the link to the two files are here github.com/logonia/ihope.git  . I may not be finish it without your help thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are looping through an array of objects although you are clicking on a specific task. Not sure why you did this, but I updated the code again, you should add it to your JavaScript / jQuery code of course, not the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".BTN_Submit_Task", function () {
    var AllTasks = ls.GetAllArr(LocalstorageName);
    var id = $(this).attr("rec_id");
    var result = $.grep(AllTasks, function(e){ return e.rec_id === id; });    

    $.ajax({
        url: "url/of/php/file.php",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {usersJSON: [result]},
        done: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

And BTW you probably want to make `AllTasks` variable global and assign it once, then you can call it from both functions.

Comment: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) " from the console at second but last line

Comment: @BernardLogonia fixed it, try now.

Comment: @BernardLogonia Did it solve your question? if so, accept this answer so it will mark as solved.